# c# Singleton Pattern with multiple DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, dll, singleton

My question is about a singleton pattern used in the following constellation of assemblies and libraries.

Imagine the following assemblies

- CommonLibrary.dll
- MainProcess.exe
- Plugin1.dll
- Plugin2.dll

MainProcess.exe, Plugin1.dll, and Plugin2.dll use the class `Manager` from CommonLibrary.dll. The CommonLibrary.dll is linked against the other assemblies at compile time. The `Manager` class uses the singleton pattern:

```
public class Manager
{
    private static Manager instance;

    public static Manager Instance
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        get { 
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Manager();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Manager()
    {

    }

    // methods ...
}
```

The singleton pattern is used to create only one instance of the `Manager` class (obviously). This is important in the methods of `Manager` because access to resources needs to be coordinated with different locks. E.g. by using lock:

```
// Method inside Manager
public void DoSomething()
{
    lock(someLockObject)
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

MainProcess.exe, Plugin1.dll, and Plugin2.dll each have a reference to the Manager somewhere in their code by calling

```
Manager manager = Manager.Instance;
// do something with manager
```

Now imagine the following scenario:
MainProcess.exe loads Plugin1.dll and Plugin2.dll using reflection during runtime using Assembly.LoadFrom();

Question: Do MainProcess.exe, Plugin1.dll, and Plugin2.dll share the **same** instance of Manager? This is important because if they do **not** share the same instance of Manager i need to do some inter process locking of resources.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do MainProcess.exe, Plugin1.dll, and Plugin2.dll share the same instance of Manager?

Yes, they do. There will be only one instance of `Manager` in the application domain (and in the whole process, unless you explicitly create another `AppDomain`).

Comment: Thank you for confirming what i hoped for. I wasn't sure because of the runtime / reflection loading of the DLLs.

Comment: +1 I am using a similar scenario with a shared project and was worried that my static object would only be available to the main program.